# .Net MVC Memory Management and Performance Improvements- Super big controllers

Tags: .net, performance

I have a .Net MVC project which has about 25 controllers, many supporting classes (mostly with static functions to provide some processing help to the code in the controllers). Then there are about 100 views that are outputted from calls to controllers, different upon what functionality was requested through a request to the controller.

Now, each of these controllers contains thousands of line of code.  My understanding is that an controller instance is created for every request and this is the cause of my concern. If an object containing thousands of line of code has to be instantiated for every HTTP call to a controller, this could be a major performance issue.

So the question is, 1) is my assumption correct that each controller object instance includes a copy of the bytecode of those thousands of line of source code?  2) Would it make the code more efficient to break the controllers down into smaller controllers? (this could be a major task because URLs pointing to old controller methods would also need to be changed in browser side javascript). 3) Any other suggestions to optimize the performance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code is immutable. It is shared between instances of the same type. Further, unused types and methods typically are not touched by the runtime at all. This is not a concern.

(2) might be useful from a code quality perspective but not from a performance perspective.

You need to profile your code to understand what's slow. I can tell from this question that your experience with performance is not enough to formulate likely hypotheses on your own. You need to learn by example first.

Comment: Is there a profiler that I can use on live application to get a better insight into performance and bottlenecks?

Comment: Yes, put 100% load on. Then pause the debugger 10 times. It will stop most in the most hot code. Otherwise, there are .NET profilers to buy.